# Function keeps executing piece of code even if changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently having a problem making a Tic-Tac-Toe game where even if i change the "state" variable it keeps executing the code inside it, how can i solve this problem? Is there a easy way to keep executing constant code for making a game?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  gameManager();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  gameManager();
});

var playerSelect, aiSelect = "";
var state = "choose";
var turn = "player";
var gameOn = true;

function gameManager() {

  if (state == "choose") {
    chooseSide();
  } else if (state == "play") {

    createGrid();

    if (turn == "player") {
      playerChoose();
      console.log("Player's turn");
    } else {
      playerChoose();
      console.log("Enemy's turn");
    }
  }
}

function playerChoose() {
  $('.gridElement').click(function() {
    $(this).html('<div class="gridElement">' + playerSelect + '</div>');
  });
}

function chooseSide() {
  console.log(state);

  $('#textContainer').html('<p> Choose Side: </p> <div class="chooseButton">X</div> <div class="chooseButton">O</div>');

  $('.chooseButton').click(function() {
    console.log(state);
    playerSelect = $(this).html();

    if (playerSelect == "X") {
      aiSelect = "O";
    } else {
      aiSelect = "X";
    }

    state = "play"
    console.log(state);
  });
}

function createGrid() {

  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    $('#gridContainer').append('<div class="gridElement"> </div>');
  }

  var gridElementSize = $('#gridContainer').width() / 3;

  $('.gridElement').css({
    'width': gridElementSize,
    "height": gridElementSize
  });
}
```

```css
#gridContainer {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.gridElement {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#textContainer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.chooseButton {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- INITIALIZE -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Shade" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Ops+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ca5f7b6f9a.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <!--CONTENT-->
  <title>TicTacToe</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="textContainer">

  </div>


  <div id="gridContainer">

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `"even if i change the "state" variable it keeps executing the code inside it"` - What does that even mean?  Can you describe the problem more clearly?  Also, why are you executing the same function twice when the document loads?  And why do you keep re-adding the same click handlers to elements?  That's going to make those elements execute the handlers *many* times.  This code is ***very*** confusing.

Comment: I want that the gameManager function keeps executing while the game is on, checking for the different states of the game to execute some other code that keeps the game working. So first i set the state to "choose" so the player chooses 'x' or 'o' then the state changes to "play" to draw the board and so it checks each turn of the game.

Comment: This sounds like an opportune time to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Take a look at your browser's debugging tools.  You can place "breakpoints" on lines of code and "step through" the code as it executes, line by line.  This will allow you to observe the runtime values of your variables and behavior of your code.  Clearly there's a mistake here, but I suspect it's being clouded by several other mistakes and the whole thing looks, well, pretty messed up.  I suspect the whole thing will start to make a lot more sense if you move those click handlers out of the functions.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on writing Javascript web applications. Javascript applications are event-driven. The function doesn't keep executing, you write event handlers that do something in response to the user performing some action, like clicking on an element.

Comment: Your function has to return so that it can then respond to the next action by the user.

Comment: Thank you! It seems my code is just not viable as i thought, i'm having many troubles making this tic tac toe, but will find another way then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bamar said, Javascript web applications are event-driven, meaning you need to create event handlers for user interactions with the web page.  Events occur when the user interacts with the browser (clicks an element on the page, scrolls the view, etc.).  Event handlers are Javascript functions.  When binding event handlers, you should only bind them once to an event type.  There are only two events in your application that need handling: choosing X or O, and clicking on a square in the grid.

I refactored your code to illustrate a better approach.  The choosing of sides is bound once in initGame, and the grid-square-click is bound to the squares when they are created (each time the game is reset by choosing sides again).  Note that it is necessary to bind the square click handler again each time the game is reset, because the previous gridElements are removed at the top of `resetGrid`, and the event handler binding to those removed elements is lost.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  initGame();
});

var playerSelect, aiSelect = "";
var turn;
var gameOn;


function initGame() {
  $('#textContainer').html('<p> Choose Side: </p> <div class="chooseButton">X</div> <div class="chooseButton">O</div>');

  $('.chooseButton').click(function(){
    playerSelect = $(this).html();

    if(playerSelect == "X"){
      aiSelect = "O";
    } else {
      aiSelect = "X";
    }
    resetGame(); 
  });

}

function resetGame(){
  gameOn = true;
  turn = "player";    
  resetGrid();
}

function resetGrid(){
  // remove any existing grid elements
  $('.gridElement').remove();

  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    $('#gridContainer').append('<div class="gridElement"></div>');
  }

  var gridElementSize = $('#gridContainer').width()/3;

  $('.gridElement').css({'width': gridElementSize, "height": gridElementSize});

  // bind the click handler to the new elements
  $('.gridElement').click(function(e){ // e is the event
    handlePlayerClick(e);
  });
}

function checkForWinOrDraw() {
  // check for win or draw
  gameOn = true; // set to false if game is over
}

function handlePlayerClick(e) { // e is the click event
  if( gameOn == false ) {
    // the current game is over, so do nothing
    return;
  }
  if(turn == "player"){
    square = $(e.target);
    if( square.html() == "") { // if the square is empty
      $(e.target).html(playerSelect); // e.target is the grid element
      turn = "enemy";
      console.log("Player has made a move");
      // the player has made a move
      checkForWinOrDraw();
      makeEnemyMove();
    } else {
      console.log("Square has already been taken.");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Player can't play.  It's the enemy's turn");
  } 

}

function makeEnemyMove() {
  if( gameOn == false ) {
    // the current game is over, so do nothing
    return;
  }
  // dumb AI picks first empty square.  Replace with smart AI
  els = $('.gridElement').toArray();
  var i;
  for( i = 0; i < els.length; i++ ) {
    var el = $(els[i]);
    if( el.html() == "" ) {
      el.html(aiSelect);
      console.log("Enemy has made a move");
      turn = "player";
      break;
    }
  }
  checkForWinOrDraw();
}
```

```css
#gridContainer{
 border: 2px solid blue;

 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;

 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 40px;
}

.gridElement{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;

 border: 1px solid black;
}

#textContainer{

 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;

}

.chooseButton{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <!-- INITIALIZE -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Shade" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Ops+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ca5f7b6f9a.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <!--CONTENT-->
  <title>TicTacToe</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="textContainer">

 </div>


 <div id="gridContainer">

 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I have no idea bout event and how they are suppose to work, i would read more about it. But your code explains it really well.